# Notifications not stacking?

Tags: android, android-notifications

Hi I'm using Firebase Cloud Messaging service for notifications.  I'm able display notifications but they are not stacking up.  In spite of any number of notifications they are displayed individually on notifications tray.  I'm using same group id for individual notifications and summary notification.  Can someone help?

Here is my code...

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    final String STORY_GROUP = "story";
    String groupId;
    NotificationManagerCompat manager;

    public MyFirebaseMessagingService() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {

            Intent intent;
            Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
            String notificationFor = data.get("notificationFor");
            String key, ownerId, picUrl, title, body,sendersUid, receiversUid, profilePicUrl, conversationId;

            if (notificationFor.equals("storyComment")) {
                key = data.get("key");
                ownerId = data.get("ownerId");
                picUrl = data.get("icon");
                title = data.get("title");
                body = data.get("body");
                groupId = STORY_GROUP;

                intent = new Intent(this, StoryDetails.class);
                intent.putExtra("key", key);
                intent.putExtra("ownerId", ownerId);

                sendNotification(intent,title,body,groupId,"New comments on your story");

           }

            Log.d("MessagingService", "Message received and has data payload :" + remoteMessage.getData());

        }

    }

    public void sendNotification(Intent intent,String title,String message,String groupId,String summaryText) {

        NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle().setSummaryText(summaryText);

        Log.d("NotificationService","groupId = " + groupId);

        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,(int) System.currentTimeMillis(),intent,0);
        Uri notificationSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                                         .setShowWhen(true)
                                         .setContentTitle(title)
                                         .setContentText(message)
                                         .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.launcher)
                                         .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                                         .setGroup(groupId)
                                         .setAutoCancel(true)
                                         .setSound(notificationSound);

        NotificationCompat.Builder group = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                                         .setGroupSummary(true)
                                         .setGroup(groupId);

        Random rand = new Random();
        int randomInt = rand.nextInt(100);
        if (manager == null) {
            manager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
        }
        manager.notify(randomInt,builder.build());
        manager.notify(1,group.build());
   }
}
```